# Laravel Migration: Rename and Add column with similar name ends up with error

Tags: laravel, database-migration

We're using Laravel Migration (`v8.x`) to alter one of our existing tables, where we want to rename a column to an existing column, but before that, we dropped it. On `up()` it's working just fine. But on the `down()`, it cannot rename the columns first and then cannot add the column. The following code is an abridged version of what we did:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('extensions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('extended_amount'); // Runs 1st.
        $table->renameColumn('extended_amount_final', 'extended_amount'); // Runs 2nd.
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('extensions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('extended_amount', 'extended_amount_final'); // Not running 1st.
        $table->decimal('extended_amount', 22, 2)->nullable(); // Error with 'duplicate column'.
    });
}
```

Somehow the rename command on `down()` is not done execution when it is starting executing the second line.

But, we tried with raw MySQL query like:

```
ALTER TABLE extensions
CHANGE extended_amount extended_amount_final DECIMAL(22,2),
ADD COLUMN extended_amount DECIMAL(22,2) NOT NULL;
```

It works just fine. So we concluded that it's a bug on Laravel migration.

But how come we alter the table in the desired fashion using Laravel migration, because we've data in it and we don't want to delete the column?

Comment: Sorry i am a little bit confused. how can you rename a column which is dropped earlier??

Comment: @MdSomir Right now, columns are `extended_amount`, `extended_amount_final`. After `up()` there will be only one: `extended_amount` (renamed from `extended_amount_final`). After `down()` there will be two columns again: `extended_amount` (newly created), `extended_amount_final` (renamed from `extended_amount`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspected the issue might be in Laravel migration. But you can still use the Laravel migration to alter the table, just separate the execution as they are not running in a way that you are expecting. We're modifying only the `down()` method, as where the issue actually is.

#### Method 1

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('extensions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('extended_amount', 'extended_amount_final');
    });
    Schema::table('extensions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->decimal('extended_amount', 22, 2)->nullable();
    });
}
```

#### Method 2

You can use the `DB` Facade to do this by raw SQL in a separate query.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('extensions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('extended_amount', 'extended_amount_final');
        // $table->decimal('extended_amount', 22, 2)->nullable();
    });
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE project_extensions ADD COLUMN extended_amount DECIMAL(22,2) NOT NULL;
}
```

Thanks to my colleagues: Ms. Mowshana Farhana and Mr. Nazmul Hasan, for assisting in debugging the issue and digging up a solution.